# Hide title on scrolling up in iphone as in recents - swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

I am trying to hide the title on scrolling up. I have a picker and 2 buttons on the bar which needs to be intact. All I want is to hide the large title on scrolling up. Kindly help. I have uploaded the code as requested

```swift
NavigationView {
    List(self.claim, id: \.name) { claim in

        NavigationLink(
            destination: ClaimViewModel(claimlist: claim),
            label: {

                HStack {
                    Image(claim.patientImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().stroke(Color(claim.claimStatusColor), lineWidth: 3))

                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Mr")
                            Text(claim.name)


                            Text("-")
                                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular))

                            Text(claim.mrn)
                                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular))

                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 5)

                        HStack {
                            Text(claim.insuranceCompany)
                                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular))

                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    Text(claim.claimStatus)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            })

    }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    .navigationBarTitle("Claim Status")
    .navigationBarItems(
        trailing:
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ClaimViewPicker()
                }

                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

                }, label: {

                    Text("Close")
                })

            })
}
```

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Comment: I have reframed the question with the code

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Something that reproduces your issue. But a few things to mention. the `navigationBar...()` are being deprecated with 14.3 so using `.toolbar` might help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey lorem, thanks for the tip. I want the same look and feel (actions) as of the recents in call history of an iphone. as the user slides up, the large title will disappear under the hheader tab